# queston about T4- spaces

Tags: general-topology

please can can anyone tell me that is it is true?
i found this statement (question) in one old book of topology. i think it is just printing mistake.
statement(question) is 
prove that every T4 space is T0 space. 
  i had tried to prove but fail. i know that in T4 space every two
disjoint closed sets have disjoint open
neighborhoods but how to prove it T0,  is the question is wrong. please help me

Comment: Sir , i read the book and reach to conclusion that  metrizable imply normal imply regular imply T2 imply T1 imply T0  this is true? 
  from this,  can we say metrizable space is also T0 space ?

Comment: It would be an improvement to give the name of the book (and author) and the numbering of the exercise (if it is one) that motivates your Question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The separation axioms are defined in such a way, that there are increasingly stronger:
$$
T_4 \Longrightarrow T_3 \Longrightarrow  T_2 \Longrightarrow  T_1 \Longrightarrow T_0.
$$
There is sometimes some confusion about the "names" of spaces satisfying certain separation axioms. For example, "normal" does not imply $T_0$ and "regular" does not imply $T_0$, see [here](http://fac.hsu.edu/worth/topology/separate.html). Hence "normal" does not imply $T_4$.

Comment: So, sir,  normal does not imply T0 but T4 imply T0.
and regular does not imply T0 but T3 imply T0,  is am i right sir.

Comment: @Akash Indeed. The indiscrete (or trivial) topology is normal and regular (trivially) but not $T_0$.

Comment: It should be noted that unfortunately there are some people who use *normal* to mean what you and I would call $T_4$ and *regular* to mean what you and I would call $T_3$, and who use $T_4$ and $T_3$ for our *normal* and *regular*, with the result that the $T_k$ no longer form a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) a $T_4$ space is Hausdorff, so it is trivially $T_0$.